# protocol error on ios and safari with http2

Tags: php, nginx, server, safari, http2

When I access this [page](https://dev.egoi.page/5efe26kF/testesfrancisco) on ios (any browser) or safari on mac,
I get the following error :

> [Error] The operation couldn’t be completed. Protocol error
> [Error] Failed to load resource: The operation couldn’t be completed. Protocol error
> [Error] The operation couldn’t be completed. Protocol error
> [Error] Failed to load resource: The operation couldn’t be completed. Protocol error

I am using nginx and php-fmf with http2 on the backend.
I can give any additional information you need.

Comment: Can you access it on any computer? Looks to be completely unavailable to me.

Comment: with safari I can't. I can with any other browser.

Comment: I can't with any browser. Sure you don't have a cached site in your other browsers?